# Easily Load Mutiple Polymer Components in Karma

Tags: polymer, karma-runner

I'm working on an app written using Polymer components and was working on automating some of the unit tests for our custom components. Ideally I'd like to be able to have something like

```
files: [
            'public/js/bower/platform/platform.js',
            'node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon-1.10.2.js',
            'public/components/*.html',
            {pattern: 'public/components/*.js', included: false, served: true},
            {pattern: 'public/js/bower/**', included: false, served: true},
            {pattern: 'public/js/*.js', included: false, served: true},
            'test/components/polymer-*-tests.js'
        ],
```

in my `karma.confg.js` file, so that it loads any components and tests we add in the future without having to manually add them. However, while this correctly results in `<link rel="import">`s for all of the components in the components folder, only the first is being properly registered by Polymer (tests for the rest are all failing). If I manually add each component to the list, such as:

```
files: [
            'public/js/bower/platform/platform.js',
            'node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon-1.10.2.js',
            'public/components/poly-component-1.html',
            'public/components/poly-component-2.html',
            'public/components/poly-component-3.html',
            {pattern: 'public/components/*.js', included: false, served: true},
            {pattern: 'public/js/bower/**', included: false, served: true},
            {pattern: 'public/js/*.js', included: false, served: true},
            'test/components/polymer-*-tests.js'
        ],
```

then everything works fine. I've also gotten it to work if I add something similar to

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'import';
link.href = 'base/public/components/<component-name>.html;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

at the beginning of each test file, or creating a bootstrap script with

```
components = [
    'polymer-component-1', 
    'polymer-component-2',
    'polymer-component-3'];

for (var i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = 'import';
    link.href = '/base/public/components/' + components[i] + '.html';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
}
```

and making sure karma loads it before the tests. However, these three solutions all involve manual edits of files (or remembering to include some boilerplate at the beginning of test files that isn't normally there).

Does anyone have any ideas as to why using the wildcard pattern seems to not be working? Karma does appear to be adding the html imports properly to the context iframes, and the html and js files for the components are being loaded into the browsers. The components just seem to not be registering.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what error message looks like when you said "tests for the rest are all failing".

However, I personally found something similar, but I nailed it down to the problem that `karma` could possibly include my html twice. See the [issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1563) I logged it to karma-runner project for more info.